# No puedo buscar segun nombre en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada deudores con 2 campos, nombre y monto, donde nombre es un `varchar` de 20 y monto un `int` de 13, el campo clave es nombre y es `único`, no puedo correr un simple query como:

```
echo implode("",mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deudores WHERE nombre=a")));
```

Ya revise los nombres y nada, la tabla no funciona, pero ejecuto una linea donde no pongo condición y si funciona:

```
echo implode("",mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deudores")));
```

la sección de código que no puedo ejecutar es esta:

```
<?php
            $datos=explode("/",$_POST['abon']);

            $montabon=$_POST['monto'];
            if($montabon>=$datos[2]||$montabon=="todo")$montabon=$datos[2];

            //Aqui
            mysql_query("UPDATE deudores SET monto=monto-".$montabon." WHERE nombre=".$datos[1]);
            //Aqui

            echo implode("",mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM deudores ")));

            if($_POST['monto']=="todo"||$_POST['monto']>=$datos[2])
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE regdeudas SET pagado=1 WHERE ID=".$datos[0],$conn);
                echo "<h1 align=\"center\">Deuda pagada completamente</h1>";
            }
            else 
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE regdeudas SET monto=monto-'$_POST[monto]' WHERE ID=".$datos[0],$conn);
                echo "<h1 align=\"center\">Monto abonado a la deuda</h1>";
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu error es en esta linea:

```
implode("",mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deudores WHERE nombre=a")));
```

Estas seleccionando un string, por lo tanto debe ser:

```
 "SELECT * FROM deudores WHERE nombre='a'"
```

las comillas son importantes para la comparación de strings

Comment: Muchas gracias, que imbecil soy

Comment: si fue útil, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Prueba tu select de la siguiente forma :

```
SELECT * FROM deudores WHERE nombre='a'

SELECT * FROM deudores WHERE nombre like '%a%'
```